# Error when trying to create an object DateTime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date, timezone

Today I got a project written in PHP. There's an error when I try to show a date in a table data set. This is the statement that generates the error:

```
$data = new DateTime($registro["previsao de entrega"];
```

The error message is this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct() Failed to parse time string (2 dez 2011
>   16:00) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character' in
>   C:\www\fluxo_producao\Telas\TelaFluxoProducao.php:941 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\www\fluxo_producao\Telas\TelaFluxoProducao.php(941):
>   DateTime->__construct('2 dez 2011 16:0...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\www\fluxo_producao\Telas\TelaFluxoProducao.php on line 941

What I discovered by myself was that if I change the parameter manually to "12 Dec 2006" for example, the function works. But the date the variable is passing is "12 Dez 2006" (Brazilian format, by the way, I'm Brazilian ^_^), and i found too that the default timezone in the server is "America/Sao_Paulo"... What do I have to change in the function or parameters to make it convert the format specified?

Comment: please output the value of `$registro["previsao de entrega"]`

Comment: what do u mean with output? do u actually wants to know the value? it's "12 Dez 2006" (without quotes) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that you have set your server to the correct time locale:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR');
```

This is required for [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and AFAIK all the date/time related functions and the `DateTime` class use the same library which will require/respect this setting.

Comment: This is exactly what I was afraid to do... because the original code is not mine... and if i change that property it would cause impact in date conversion on another peaces of code... =/ Is this the only way?

Comment: Haha... i'm gonna do that... hope i don't get too much impact in the rest of the code... Just give me a clue... Where's the best place to put this setting? First of all code?

Comment: Well you could set it before you execute this specific code, then set it back afterwards?

Comment: =) Good idea xD It'd never pass through my mind haha. ;) Thx.. I'm gonna see if it will work and come back here to tell u =)

Comment: Ah, just one more thing... to set the LC_TIME back... what's the default?

Comment: That would depend on your system. I suspect it will use the default locale for the OS, annoyingly PHP doesn't provide a `getlocale()` function, and there seems to be a dearth of information on the internet on how to find it. Is the majority of your app in english? If so, you could probably fairly safely just use `en_US`.

Comment: Actually the app is is brazilian portuguese... i found that on google:

echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);

and it returned:

LC_COLLATE=C;LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C

I think the default locale is already pt_BR =/ What do i do now?

Comment: Searchin once more, i found the the parameter of datetime must be inenglish... how do i convert my date in pt-br to en?

Comment: I'm afraid you're probably stuck with `str_replace(array('Dez', ...), array('Dec', ...), $str)`

Comment: I thought about that... But how will be my performance if i do such conversion one thousand times? I'm very concerned about that...

Comment: Where is this data coming from? I know you say it is coming from the DB, but is it a `varchar` field or what? I'm wondering if you could do the conversion at insert time, rather than when displaying it - then you would only need to do it once. Or better yet, store it as a `datetime` or `int`

Comment: it's a datetime field (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM)

Comment: Can you double check the DB schema on that? When selecting a `datetime` field, you should get a string in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, if you are not I suspect it is actually a `varchar` or `char`... What Db are you using?

Comment: SQL Server... I'd like to know whoy php is converting the data from the format (2011-02-13 00:00) to (13 Fev 2011 00:00)...

Comment: Maybe [this](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/setting-a-standard-dateformat-for-sql-se) will help you?

Comment: Well, i gave up. xD I decided to use str_replace as u'd suggested... I wont care about the performance... It's not my code... and i'm already tired of spendin my time and your time trying to convert a simple date =P Man i really thank you ^_^

Answer (score 1):

It needs to have a closing curly bracket on the end?

```
$data = new DateTime($registro["previsao de entrega"]);
```

If this is just a typo it could be the value of `$registro["previsao de entrega"]` is incorrect, what is it?

You can see allowed value formats here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

It will only accept English month values, eg, `Dec` will work but `Dez` will not.

Comment: Well, the variable $registro["previsao de entrega"] is how I access the value returned from a database...

Comment: Hummm... I see... But i'ts Dec because PHP is converting it to my timezone format... =/ What do i do?

Comment: `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR');`

Comment: This is one of the problems i found... my default locale already is 'pt_BR'... What i figured is that PHP is retrieving the date from the database in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM" and is setting the variable automatically to the pt-bR format =/ Any ideas?