# PHP setlocale on WAMP fail for pt_BR

Tags: php, timezone

Ok, what's wrong here?

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');

echo "<p>São Paulo, " . date("d \d\e F \d\e Y", time()) . "</p>";

echo "<p>Preferred locale on this system is '" . setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) . "'</p>";
```

echoes:

```
São Paulo, 24 de April de 2012
Preferred locale on this system is 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252'
```

Tried also something like:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252', 'bra', 'brazil', 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese', 'portuguese-brazil', 'ptb');
```

But nothing makes the 'aPril' becomes 'aBril'.

thx.

PS: Document is UTF.8 (without BOM) formated on IDE.

Comment: This is a common problem - I have seen a different version of exactly this question [on here before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030437). Maybe [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=664705) will help? The long of the short of it is that you need to install the pt_BR locale on your server machine.

Comment: @DaveRandom I've checked the server config, apache and php itself. (even timezone config). None is misconfigured. Also as seen on the test above the setlocale returns correctly given the preferred locale for the systes is already portuguese_brasil.1252.

Comment: Have you checked if pt_BR has month name set correctly? I mean maybe it's 'April' in locale itself.

Comment: @c2h5oh how would I check this? On Server OS? PHP config?

Comment: OS - does the date display right in Windows?. Also I have just checked and there is no pt_BR locale on Windows, only "Portuguese_Brazil.1252" - setting locale to pt_BR does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue on a shared hosting and just made my own locale function.

**UPDATE:**

Well if you have installed the language just use strftime() instead of date()

From PHP documentation:

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and strftime() 
>   functions instead of date().

Try this:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
//setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252'); ERROR in nowadays
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf-8'); // UTF-8 is the correct!

echo "<p>São Paulo, " . strftime("%d de %B de %Y", time()) . "</p>";

echo "<p>Preferred locale on this system is '" . setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) . "'</p>";
```

Comment: seems a good function, but what I'm looking for is how to setup correctly. thx.

Comment: ERROR: the webpage is not for your Windows, is for readers, and they are not "charset Windows 1252" users, they use UTF8 (!). Is more correct to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf-8')`.

Answer (score -1):

`strftime("%d de %B de %Y", time()).`
 Work!!